# How to change number of parallel processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a python script which runs a method in parallel.

```
parsers = {
    'parser1': parser1.process,
    'parser2': parser2.process
}

def process((key, value)):
    parsers[key](value)

pool = Pool(4)
pool.map(process_items, items)
```

`process_items` is my method and `items` is a list of tuples with two elements to each tuple. The `items` list has around 100k items.

`process_items` will then call a method depending on what parameters are given. My problem being maybe 70% of the list I can run with high parallelism but the other 30% can only run with 1/2 threads otherwise will cause a failure outside of my control.

So in my code I have around 10 different parser processes. For say 1-8 I want to run with Pool(4) but 9-10 Pool(2).

What is the best way to optimise this?

Comment: Could you just use two pools? First, create a pool that uses all your cores,  iterate over the list, filter out entries that need reduced parallelism, and call `pool1.map` on the remaining items. Then close/join that pool. Then create a new pool with fewer processes, and call `map` on only the entries in the iterable that *do* need reduced parallelism.

Comment: This was the only option I could think of, I was hoping there might be a cleaner way? Or maybe this is clean enough?

Comment: The other options I can think of are probably *less* clean - you'd need some kind of synchronization across all your workers to handle it with just one `Pool`. And you'd also need to deal with cases where some workers are busying working when you get to items that need reduced parallelism, which means you'd need to wait until other workers are done before processing it. It seems like it'd end up being messy to get right.

Comment: It's also potentially inefficient, if you hit a couple of "low parallelism" items in a row, you'll need to wait around for currently running "high parallelism" items to finish, even though there might be other "high parallelism" items waiting to be processed in the pool's queue, which would be running in the meantime. The `Pool` doesn't have any way to re-enqueue an item from the worker, so I don't think there's any way to avoid that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best option is to use two pools here:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
# import parsers here

parsers = {
    'parser1': parser1.process,
    'parser2': parser2.process,
    'parser3': parser3.process,
    'parser4': parser4.process,
    'parser5': parser5.process,
    'parser6': parser6.process,
    'parser7': parser7.process,
}

# Sets that define which items can use high parallelism,
# and which must use low
high_par = {"parser1", "parser3", "parser4", "parser6", "parser7"}
low_par = {"parser2", "parser5"}

def process_items(key, value):
    parsers[key](value)

def run_pool(func, items, num_items, check_set):
    pool = Pool(num_items)
    out = pool.map(func, (item for item in items if item[0] in check_set))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return out

if __name__ == "__main__":
    items = [('parser2', x), ...] # Your list of tuples
    # Process with high parallelism
    high_results = run_pool(process_items, items, 4, high_par)
    # Process with low parallelism
    low_results = run_pool(process_items, items, 2, low_par)
```

Trying to do this in one `Pool` is possible, through clever use of synchronization primitives, but I don't think it will end up looking much cleaner than this. It's also could end up running less efficiently, since sometimes your pool will need to wait around for work to finish, so it can process a low parallelism item, even when high parallelism items are available behind it in the queue.

This would get complicated a bit if you needed to get the results from each `process_items` call in the same order as they fell in the original iterable, meaning the results from each `Pool` need to get merged, but based on your example I don't think that's a requirement. Let me know if it is, and I'll try to adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks ill give this a go. This is probably the best way as I want to keep things simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the number of parallel threads in the constructor for [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(5)   # 5 is the number of parallel threads
    print pool.map(f, [1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Sorry I updated my question as i did not explain myself correctly. I already have set the processes its just one/two of my processes can't run at that parallelism and will fail.